# Unable to set value of FormField.Result if it is not set to Fill-in Enabled

Tags: vba, ms-word, form-fields

Beginning in build 2102 of MS Word, a very elaborate document that I have created no longer works properly.

My form makes extensive use of FormFields. Starting with build 2102, it appears that Word VBA is not able to properly execute this command:

```
ActiveDocument.FormFields("MyFieldNameA1").Result = 100
```

if the field in question has fill-in enabled set to off.  It instead changes another, seemingly random field in the document.

There is no way that this is intended behavior.

Comment: Cross-posted at: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/confirmed-word-vba-bug-on-build-2102-how-to-report/233e32f2-cd19-4ef1-a048-9e2bb710b079
For cross-posting etiquette, please read: http://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184

Answer (score 1):

You can work around this via:

```
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("MyFieldNameA1").Range.Fields(1).Result.Text = 100
```

This is a long-standing approach to programmatically inserting strings longer than 255 characters into formfields. Works just as well with shorter strings.

Comment: I can confirm that this appears to work, however, my '=' is a not 100 but a formula and the result is not placed in the format specified by the formfield's properties (#,##0.00), like it was when changing the formfield.result.  I now have to go through one more step to format the text of the formula's result.  And as you have said, this is a work around, not what I would consider a 'fix'.

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant no disrespect and did not mean to be rude. I simplified my example code to make the description easier so your solution absolutely fixed my stated problem. I am frustrated that the code I've had in place for years worked in versions prior to version 2102 and became 'broken' in the most recent version of Word.  What I did to solve this in my particular case was set each field to "fill-in enabled" and then created an "On Entry" macro for each of these fields that does:  ActiveDocument.FormFields("MyFieldNameA1").Next.Select, which prevents a user from filling in the field.

Comment: Doubtless MS will release an update to fix the problem. That doesn't help much in the interim, though.

Answer (score 0):

Build 13801.20808 of version 2102 Word is affected, however this was fixed by Microsoft in at least build 13801.20960. Just for documentation as I just came across this problem.